# where to display $_SESSION variable below

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve a name of the file uploaded and append it into .list. The problem is that the file name it is retrieving from the $_SESSION variable is always the last file updated and then it doesn't change.

For example if I upload these files below in the server:

```
desert.jpg
tulips.jpg
lighthouse.jpg
desert_2.jpg
```

Then the file names it should append from $_SESSION should be:

```
desert.jpg
tulips.jpg
lighthouse.jpg
desert_2.jpg
```

But instead it is appending this below for file names retrieved from $_SESSION on screen:

```
desert.jpg
desert.jpg
desert.jpg
desert.jpg
```

How can it be fixed so that when a file is uploaded onto the server, it's file name is appended onto .list?

Below is the javascript function where $_SESSION variable is in the json code which displays the name of the file on the screen by appending it onto .list:

```
  function stopImageUpload(success){

          var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']['name']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage']['name'] : null); ?>;
          if (success == 1){
             $('.listImage').append(imagename + '<br/>');
          }
          else {

            $('.listImage').append('No File');
          }

    return true;

    }
```

Below is the php code where it uploads the file:

```
<?php

session_start();

$result = 0;
$errors = array ();
$dirImage = "ImageFiles/";

$allowedTypes = array (
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/gif",
        "image/pjpeg",
        "image/jpg",
        "image/png",
        "image/tif" 
);

if (isset ( $_FILES ['fileImage'] ) && $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $fileName = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['size'];
    $fileTemp = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['type'];

    $fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    $fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );

    if (empty ( $fileName ))
        continue;

    if (! in_array ( $fileType, $allowedTypes )) {
        $errors [] = "File Type is not accepted";

    }

    if(!is_writable($dirImage ))
    {
        $errors [] = "File Destination not writeable";
    }


    $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
    $filePrifix = basename ( $fileName, "." . $fileExt );
    $i = 0;
    while ( file_exists ( $fileDst ) ) {
        $i ++;
        $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePrifix . "_" . $i . "." . $fileExt;

    }
    // Move the file

    if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
        if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
            $result = 1;


        }
    }

}

$_SESSION ['fileImage'][] = $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'];

?>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);</script>
```

On seperate page I have a JSON which retrieves the $_SESSION:

```
function stopImageUpload(success){

      var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] : null); ?>;
      if (success == 1){
         $('.listImage').append(imagename + '<br/>');
      }
      else {
        $('.listImage').append('<br/>');
      }

return true;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$_SESSION ['fileImage'][] = $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'];` instead of `$_SESSION ['fileImage']['name'] = $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'];`

Comment: I have a slight problem with this, I am using JSON to retrieve the $_SESSION variable from another page and if I call the session as you have called it above, then it doesn't load the page where the JSON is displayed. Why is this happening? Code is updated to show what current code now looks like

Comment: Structure of your `$_SESSION` array has changed. Modify your second part of script to handle those changed array properly.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is still doing the same thing when change $_SESSION code in the Json encode. Was this what you wanted me to do?

Comment: No ) . I mean your json_ecoded `$_SESSION` array now has another structure so your script that accept json_encoded string should now that there is no 'name' index in `$_SESSION ['fileImage']`.

Comment: so it should be $_SESSION ['fileImage']['name'] in json.encode? If I change it to this then it keeps displaying 'null' rather than the name of the file uploaded

Comment: No. Now you have only `$_SESSION ['fileImage']` array which contains all filenames like `$_SESSION ['fileImage'] = array('file1.jpg', 'file2.png');`.

Comment: I am getting confused now, how is it suppose to be written is JSON code? It isn't `var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage'] = array();) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] = array(); : null); ?>;` because that is giving me an error

Comment: The json.encode code before your change was `var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']['name']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage']['name'] : null); ?>;` and the $_SESSION code in php script was `$_SESSION ['fileImage']['name'] = $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'];`

Comment: The error I am getting when adding = array(); in json code is: unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: so now you need `var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] : null); ?>;` but now you have image names ARRAY in `var imagename`, not one name

Comment: when I change var imagename to what you have told me to change it in previous comment, now I am back to the start of the problem where it just appends the name of one file and only one file. If you read question again where I mention how it is displaying file names then you can see what I mean.

Comment: Pay attention: not `var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage'][]) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'][] : null); ?>;` but `var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] : null); ?>;`

Comment: Yes I know, this is what I changed it to, that is why I said 'when I change var imagename to what you have told me in previous comment'. I was referring to when you told me to change it to `var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] : null); ?>;`. I update code above to show you current code.

Comment: So vhat is your `$_SESSION ['fileImage']`? Is it still null?

Comment: No, $_SESSION  ['fileImage'] is just displaying 1 file name. E.g. If I upload files tulips.png, tomcat.png and angel.png, it should append (look at javascript code to see how append code) tulips.png, tomcat.png and angel.png, but instead it is only appending this: tulips.png, tulips.png, tulips.png. Now when I refresh page and upload files keyboard.png and bottle.png, it should append keyboard.png and bottle.png but instead it appends this: angel.png, angel.png. This is because after I refresh page, the last file uploaded to the server was angel so it is only appending that name for any files.

Comment: so call `var_dump($_SESSION ['fileImage'])` after adding all filenames to array. It should show you it's dump.