# it is only displaying one file name

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a $_SESSION variable which should display names of files which have been uploaded. The problem is that it is not doing this, it is only display the name of a file for 1 file and 1 file only. For example if I upload files 'jellyfish.png' and 'tulips.png', it should display the file names 'jellyfish.png' and 'tulips.png' for `$_SESSION['fileImage'];` but instead it is displaying both file names as the first name like this: 'jellyfish.png' and 'jellyfish.png'.

When I do a `var_dump($_SESSION ['fileImage']);` for the example above, it outputs this: `string(13) "Jellyfish.jpg"`, no matter which file is uploaded. If I refresh the browser and lets say the last file I uploaded into the server was 'tulips.png', then it outputs this: `string(10) "tulips.jpg"`, for every file no matter which file is uploaded before the next refresh.

Does anyone know how  to fix this so it displays the correct file names for each uploaded file under the $_SESSION variable?

Below is the php script:

```
<?php

session_start();

$dirImage = "ImageFiles/";

if (isset ( $_FILES ['fileImage'] ) && $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $_SESSION ['fileImage'] = $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'];

    $fileName = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];

    $fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    $fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );


    $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
    $filePrifix = basename ( $fileName, "." . $fileExt );
    $i = 0;
    while ( file_exists ( $fileDst ) ) {
        $i ++;
        $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePrifix . "_" . $i . "." . $fileExt;


    }
    // Move the file

    if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
        if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
            $result = 1;


        }
    }

}

?>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);</script>
```

Below is the Javascript code which contains the JSON:

```
function stopImageUpload(success){

      var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] : null); ?>;
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
         $('.listImage').append(imagename + '<br/>');
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }

return true;

}

<?php
var_dump($_SESSION ['fileImage']);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you deleting and re adding this question ???? Some of us have good memory you know

Comment: possible duplicate of [where to display $_SESSION variable below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278801/where-to-display-session-variable-below)

Answer (score 3):

Session is not working because you copied a script written by me and deleted the question, not adding it as a new question for the 3rd time .. if you wrote the script your self you should have been able to correct that simple error

Let this be the very last time you do such

Replace

```
  $_SESSION ['fileImage'] = $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'];
```

with

```
 $_SESSION ['fileImage'][] = $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'];
```

Comment: `Let this be the very last time you do such` :)

Comment: @Baba The reason I deleted this question was because your answer in previous question did not solve anything (as people saw me and you working on an answer in previous question, I believe they did not try to add their own answer) and it still doesn't solve it. If I change the $_SESSION variable to what you have stated, it doesn't work as it keeps displaying 'null' when appending the $_SESSION. I have deleted previous question because I only got 27 views in 10 hours, on this question I got 23 views in 11 mins. That is why I deleted the previous questions and add this question

Comment: 1. Simple .. just update the answer next time 2. If it does solve the problem you don't have to use my answer to create a new question 3 times 3.Its not all about view its about you getting your result .. if 1 view solves your problem what do you need 23 for 4. If you continue to delete how do other people learn ????

Comment: @Baba, 1. I updated answer last time and comment to you the problem. I waited for over 9 hours and I had no comment or reply from you. 2. I don't have to use your answer but it will be nice that before you post your answer, that you make sure your answer is correct. If it is not correct then look at my comments when I said it is not correct. 3. Other users have seen your answer posted and because of this they don't answer the question because they think an answer is already there for the question or that I am discussing an answer with you. 4. More views means more chance of correct answer.

Comment: @Baba continue from last comment ... I only had 27 views over 10 hours last time, meaning there is very little chance I get an answer at a reasonable time.

Comment: Its not a debate ... it shows you don't want to lean ... Its only a matter of time others would notice your trend .. Good luck fishing for  views